# Will the 2016 Perseid meteor shower be visible in Sydney, Australia?

Tags: meteor-shower

As the title states, will viewers in Sydney, Australia be able to see the Perseid meteor shower in August, 2016? Assume the viewer is well outside of the city and light pollution is a minimal problem.

According to [Australian Geographic](http://www.australiangeographic.com.au/news/2016/08/perseid-meteor-shower-to-put-on-special-show-up-north), the event will be visible in the northern parts of the country – specifically, "head north for the best chance to witness the event" – but it is not clear whether it will be possible to see anything in the southern parts.

If any viewing *is* possible, what would be the recommended dates and time of night to see the most?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [International Meteor Organization calendar](http://imo.net/calendar) for 2016, page 12, gives the Perseid radiant declination as +58$^\circ$ and says "regrettably, it cannot be properly viewed from most of the southern hemisphere."
At latitude -34$^\circ$ the radiant never rises above the horizon, so there may be fewer Perseid meteors than sporadic non-Perseids.
This does not change year to year as the AG article seems to suggest.
What does vary is interference from the Moon; this year it's full on the 18th, so the article is correct to recommend the morning or two before the predicted peak on August 12-13.
Also check your local weather forecast.
The predawn hours, e.g. 2 hours before sunrise, are generally best for meteors because the morning side is forward as the Earth orbits the Sun.